# standard deviation area in hysteresis like plot using ggplot in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, stdev

I'm trying to plot an hysteresis like curve (mean of other curves) using ggplot2, and I would like to have the area of the standard deviation appear over it.

I'm using the following code:

```
xlabel <- "E [V]"
ylabel <- "I[pA]"
plotdata <- data.frame(x = x21, 
                       y = probe_02_cv$Mean, 
                       lower = (probe_02_cv_m), 
                       upper = (probe_02_cv_M))

ggplot(plotdata) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = probe_02_cv$Mean, x = x21, colour = "Mean probe2")) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper, x = x21, fill = "st.dev"), alpha = 1) +
  scale_colour_manual("", values = "blue") +
  scale_fill_manual("", values = "grey12") + 
  xlab(xlabel) + 
  ylab(ylabel)
```

and graphically the result isn't very readable...

[image]

Anyone has a good idea on how to solve this?

Comment: Don't use `$` inside `aes()`, just use column names. If you need more help than that try [making a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/903061) (see link for a good how-to) either by sharing code to simulate data, sharing your data copy/pastably (use `dput()`), or using built-in data.

Comment: tried to remove $ in    aes() but no change in the graph...

Comment: Well, then to quote my above comment "*try making a [reproducible example (see link for a good how-to)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/903061) either by sharing code to simulate data, sharing your data copy/pastably (use dput()), or using built-in data*".

Comment: i managed to get over it using  the polygon function. thanks